# dropdown values from return jquery ajax success

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax

in jquery ajax, i get the values from the database and need to display in drop down. first i pass the id and fetch the level. with tat level id and name, again i fetch the values related to the selected level and display in the dropdown from the return jquery ajax object.

not inserting the result in drop down (testing function)

```
function Level(Id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetLevel' + '/?Id=' + Id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            testing(value.Value);
        },
        complete: function () { },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });    
}

function testing(LevelId) {
    result = getDropdownValues();
        $('#drp >option').remove();
        for (var i = result.length; i--; ) {
            $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                $("#drp").append($("<option></option>").val(value.Key).html(value.Value));
            });
            //not inserting the result in drop down
            //from the return object.
        }
    }
}

function getDropdownValues (LevelId, selectedLevel) {
    var passVal = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetValues' + '/?selectedLevel=' + selectedLevel + '&LevelId=' + LevelId,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            passVal = result;
        },
        complete: function () { },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
    return passVal;
}
```

and using the c# class

```
public class Level
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ListEntity> Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: not generating the dropdown list.

Comment: Could you edit your question to state where exactly your problem lies? Are you getting no data back at all from the server? Or are you just unsure on how to get this data into a dropdown list?

Comment: problem is in testing function. drop down was empty

Answer (score 0):

Your getDropdownValues function requires you to pass in the `LevelId` and `selectedLevel` parameters, but when you call it from your testing function you are not passing these in. So presumably your GetValues service is failing to return any results.

Comment: by passing values also the dropdown was empty. 
    result = getDropdownValues(LevelId,selectedLevel);
    alert(result);
it shows as [object Object], but not displaying the values

Comment: Then the issue doesn't appear to be related to the dropdowns and is to do with your ajax call. There isn't enough information here to determine what that problem might be. Have you implemented other webservice calls fine? What strikes me first as odd is that you are making a POST call in to your service. Remove jQuery from the equation and determine that your service is executing fine before proceeding.